Time-dependent effects: tt function using nsk () in coxph()
I am using coxph() to compare tree seedling survival data between three treatments (Large, Small, Control). However, coxzph() showed that the coefficient for the Small treatment differed with time. To address this, I've added a tt(Small) to the coxph (), with the nsk() to allow for a regression spline and I'm using indicator variables for Treatment.
My question is, how are the coefficients interpreted when using the tt() with the nsk(), specifically for the time-dependent variable?
Below is the model output.
cox.tt4 <-  coxph (Surv (no.yrs.alive, censor) ~ Large + Small +
                     tt(Small) + frailty (Line), data = spruce.complete,
                   tt = function (x,t,...) x*nsk(t, knots = c(3)))
summary(cox.tt4)
## Call:
## coxph(formula = Surv(no.yrs.alive, censor) ~ Large + Small + 
##     tt(Small) + frailty(Line), data = spruce.complete, tt = function(x, 
##     t, ...) x * nsk(t, knots = c(3)))
## 
##   n= 96, number of events= 35 
## 
##               coef   se(coef) se2    Chisq DF   p      
## Large         -2.520 0.7409   0.7396 11.57 1.00 0.00067
## Small         -3.427 1.2067   1.2065  8.07 1.00 0.00450
## tt(Small)1     3.056 1.7592   1.7585  3.02 1.00 0.08200
## tt(Small)2     3.183 1.4072   1.4061  5.12 1.00 0.02400
## frailty(Line)                         6.24 2.33 0.06000
## 
##            exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
## Large        0.08044   12.43122  0.018830    0.3436
## Small        0.03249   30.77809  0.003052    0.3458
## tt(Small)1  21.23826    0.04708  0.675532  667.7166
## tt(Small)2  24.12159    0.04146  1.529754  380.3560
## gamma:L1     1.06620    0.93791  0.575824    1.9742
## gamma:L2     0.59206    1.68903  0.283618    1.2359
## gamma:L3     1.27464    0.78454  0.713532    2.2770
## gamma:L5     1.39426    0.71722  0.780017    2.4922
## gamma:L6     0.67284    1.48624  0.326825    1.3852
## 
## Iterations: 6 outer, 22 Newton-Raphson
##      Variance of random effect= 0.1925677   I-likelihood = -134.1 
## Degrees of freedom for terms= 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.3 
## Concordance= 0.813  (se = 0.041 )
## Likelihood ratio test= 44.22  on 6.32 df,   p=9e-08

The time-dependent Therneau et al. 2024 vignette, Section 4.2, states that "the coefficients are the predicted values at knots 2, 3, ... - the predicted value at knot 1".
In this case, does that mean that the coefficient for the Small Treatment for the first time period (time 0 to time 3) would be, -3.427 + 3.056 = -0.371? And for the 2nd time period (> time 3), -3.427 + 3.056 = -0.244?
In addition, can I exponentiate these coefficients to calculate the hazard ratio relative to the reference treatment, with the hazard ratios differing between the two time periods?
I'm new to this method and would greatly appreciate any insight or advice.

@EdM, any chance you might know? I've found your comments very helpful in learning this method and would appreciate any advice.

The callout to a user with "@" only works in a comment thread in which that user is already engaged.

The nsk() function in the survival package is a variant of the splines::ns() cubic regression spline function that uses both a different spline basis and a different choice of positions of boundary knots. Although you only specified a single knot with nsk(t, knots = c(3)), its default arguments b = 0.05, Boundary.knots = quantile(x, c(b, 1 - b)) also placed knots at the 5th and 95th percentiles of the time values. That gives a total of 3 knots (hence the 2 coefficients for tt(Small)).
The spline basis used by nsk() (with its default intercept = FALSE argument) does mean that tt(Small)1 and tt(Small)2 are the differences of the coefficients at the time points of the second and third knots from that at the first knot. As the Cox regression coefficients are in log-hazard scales, exponentiating them does give corresponding hazard ratios.
Although the reported coefficients have that interpretation, nsk() does not fit a set of hazard ratios that are constant within the defined time periods, as you evidently assume. It fits a continuous, smooth regression spline that happens to have that interpretation at those particular time points.
Further complicating interpretation is the way that you specified nsk() with default boundary knot positions. The first knot is at the 5th percentile of the time values, not at 0. (You really don't want a knot at time=0 anyway, as there is no hazard at that time in standard survival models.) The vignette specifies Boundary.knots = FALSE and an entire set of internal knots for time. That way you know the actual times of the knots.
Instead of trying to parcel out the interpretation of individual coefficients for regression-spline terms (with any spline basis), I find it safest just to plot predictions from the model as a function of the continuous variable that's modeled with the spline. As the cox.zph() function doesn't work on models fit with tt() functions, you should do that anyway to see how well you have matched the form of the time-varying coefficient values indicated by the plot of scaled Schoenfeld residuals for Small in the model that indicated the problem with the proportional hazards assumption.

Thank you so much for your thorough response!
